# C# Visual Studio 2010 Add-in project not able to load the MySQL.Data dll at runtime

Tags: mysql, add-in

I am trying to connect to the Mysql database from an add-in project in Visual Studio 2010.I am using windows form in my add-in and on click of one of the button i have kept the connection to be made for Mysql. 
But it is throwing exception of could not find the referenced assembly or one or more of its dependent assembly.

While debugging it throws exception as soon it hits the point where the reference for MySql.Data.dll is required.

I tried connecting to the database using normal windows application. It is working fine there but in the add-in project only it is throwing error.

Please let me know if have any pointers.

Comment: Do you have the MySQL.Data.dll in Bin directory? If not, mark the reference as "Copy to Local"